# Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \ ). Not able to put regex pattern in a string

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to put a regex pattern but not able to do so. This is the regex pattern:

```
/(?:^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/|\/\/)((?:[\w.:-]+)(?:(?:[\/]+)(?!acl-)|["\'])(?:[^\s"\'}\]]*)))/mi
```

Please help me. I would be more than thankful to you.

Comment: escape all the backslashes one more time.

Comment: I have tried it. Its not working.

Comment: All slashes must be escaped :O

Comment: This is the outcome.

Comment: In future, please show *what* you've tried. You've shown the regex pattern you're trying to achieve (which escapes forward slashes for no obvious reason) but you haven't shown what your attempted Java code looks like, which would need to escape the backslashes in a string literal. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: `which escapes forward slashes for no obvious reason)`, no in js you must need to escape the forward slashes when the pattern was given within `/` delimiters. I think op was trying to convert the js regex to java regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/(?:^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/|\/\/)((?:[\w.:-]+)(?:(?:[\/]+)(?!acl-)|["\'])(?:[^\s"\'}\]]*)))/mi
```

Equivalent Java regex for the above is,

```
"(?m)(?i)(?:^(http://|https://|//)((?:[\\w.:-]+)(?:/+(?!acl-)|[\"'])(?:[^\\s\"'}\\]]*)))"
```

`(?m)` called multiline modifier and `(?i)` called case-insensitive modifier. You don't need to escape the forward slashes and single quotes but you must escape the double quotes. You could also combine the above modifiers as `(?mi)` or `(?im)` and `(http://|https://|//)` could be written as `((?:https?:)?//)`

Comment: Thanks. I will accept your answer after 10 minutes.

Comment: You can put both flags together, e.g. `(?im)`